# How to get an array from a single field from related model in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

The following:

```
Customer::with('tickets:customer_id,subject')->get();
```

returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Test Ltd",
    "support": "Standard",
    "tickets": [
      {
        "customer_id": "1",
        "name": "Test ticket 1"
      },
      {
        "customer_id": "1",
        "name": "Test ticket 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I flatten the related field, `tickets` to get:

```
tickets: ["Test ticket 1", "Test ticket 2"]
```

I tried doing a `->flatten()` after `->get()` but that didn't work at all.

It feels like it should be something simple that I'm missing and just can't find in the docs or by googling (thanks for the word `with`, that screws pretty much all sane results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this out but using `->map()` might help you in this instance:

```
$customers = Customer::with('tickets:customer_id,name')
    ->get()
    ->map(function($customer, $key) {
        $customer->tickets = $customer->tickets->pluck('name')->all();
        return $customer;
    })->all();
```

`->pluck()` will return only the value of the `key` specified.

#### Update

This can be achieved by running a query within map and avoiding eager loading:

```
$customers = Customer::all()
    ->map(function($customer, $key) {
        $customer['tickets'] = $customer->tickets()->get()->pluck('name')->all();
        return $customer;
    })->all();
```

Comment: `map()` was the answer, however Laravel doesn't allow me to assign over the existing property, so instead of `$customer->tickets =` I did `$customer->TTs =` and then hid the tickets with `->withHide('tickets')` on the `return`. Thanks!

Comment: Thats understandable. Alternatively, you could avoid eager loading `tickets` and run a new query within the `->map()` settings `$customer['tickets']`. Thats only if you want to avoid hiding `tickets` after the map.